# Is it a problem if I forget to add IEEE copyright clearance code?

Tags: publications, copyright, ieee

My paper has been accepted at an IEEE conference. The author instructions state clearly that I should add the "copyright clearance code" myself. I forgot to do so in the final version of the manuscript that should be going into print. Will this be a problem or even grounds for rejection?

Answer (score 1):

The editor should sort this out, you could always let them know.